# strstr not working correctly in kernel space

Tags: c, windows, kernel

If the process name is "System" do not DbgPrint. If it is any other process ok fine now DbgPrint but for some reason it's not working like it's supposed to.

I've tried:
if( strstr( ImageName, "System" ) != NULL ) {

if( strncmp( ImageName, "System", 6 ) != NULL ) {

if( RtlCompareMemory( ImageName, "System", length ) == length) {

I only want it to print if it is NOT "System"

Code that is not working below:

```
int ThreadHooK( PEPROCESS Process, DWORD dw, HANDLE Handle, KPROCESSOR_MODE PreviousMode ){             
    char *ImageName = (char*)(Process + 0x2e0);
    char *System = "System";
    if( PreviousMode == KernelMode ) {
        if( strstr( ImageName, System ) == NULL ) {
            DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[ThreadHooK]:  Attempt To Close The Handle: [0x%016X] To A Process Opened By A Kernel Process : [%s]\n", Handle, (PUCHAR)Process + 0x2e0 );
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I hope someone can fix this

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `strcmp`?  If you use `strstr`, it will look for any matching substring.  You would use `if (strcmp(ImageName, "System") != 0) { ... }`

Comment: I fixed it: char *ImageName = (char*)((PUCHAR)Process + 0x2e0); Took me a bit to realize I messed up on math. DUH...

Comment: Where does the magic number 0x2e0 come from?

Comment: Don't forget to replace `strstr` with `strcmp`.  And don't use `strncmp`, which will only look for prefixes.  Keep it simple.

Comment: `PEPROCESS` is a pointer to an `EPROCESS` struct. Would it not be saner to use `Process->ImageFileName`? (I'm guessing that's the member you want to use.)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change this line:

```
char *ImageName = (char*)(Process + 0x2e0);
```

to this:

```
char *ImageName = (char*)((PUCHAR)Process + 0x2e0);
```